# Azure Open AI service - custom model

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai

I created an Azure Open AI service
I want to train the model for specific questions.
However, the customize template buttons are disabled.
In the documentation it says how to generate the .Jsonl with the questions and answers to train, but there is nothing to import these files.
Anyone got it yet?[image: in my panel this option is disabled.]

*in my panel this option is disabled.*

this link is nice, but nothing works in my panel.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ai-services/openai/media/fine-tuning/studio-models.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason for `create a custom model` option to be `disabled` is you that haven't been granted a **Cognitive Services OpenAI Contributor"** role assignment in resource level.

Below I don't have the role assigned.

[image]

To Assign the role you can follow the below steps:

Select Add role assignment in IAM
[image]

Assign the below Role under your user account.

[image]

One you assign the role; you will be able to access the required option.
[image]

Comment: I will run the solution and check, it makes sense. even though I am the owner of the account